# javascript unkown error on css code line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this html table:

```
<center><input type="button" value="Print last visit report" id="printpagebutton" onclick="printData()"/>
      <input type="button" value="Print all reports" id="printpagebutton2" onclick="printData1()"/>
    </center></BR>
<center></center>
<div class=WordSection1 id="mydiv1">
<?php while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  $data2 =$rows['echo_files'];
$dataFile2 = str_replace('/', '\\', $data2); ?>


<div id="mydiv">
  <form action="/clinic form/update/update.php" id="Form2" method="post">
<table border="1" align="center" id="table">
<tr align="center">
<th colspan="3" bgcolor="#7a7878">DR. Omar GHNEIM - Patient Medical History</th>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<th colspan="3"><?php echo 'Medical History of '.$rows['name']?></th>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Medicaments</th>
    <th>Illness</th>
    <th>Echo Results</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <?php if(!empty($rows['remarcs']) && trim($rows['remarcs'])!=''):?>
    <td width="250px"><?php echo $rows['remarcs'] ?></td>
    <?php else: ?>
    <td width="250px" align="center">Not Available</td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(!empty($rows['illness']) && trim($rows['illness'])!=''):?>
    <td width="250px"><?php echo $rows['illness'] ?></td>
        <?php else: ?>
    <td width="250px" align="center">Not Available</td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(!empty($rows['echo']) && trim($rows['echo'])!=''):?>
    <td width="250px"><?php echo $rows['echo'] ?></td>
    <?php else: ?>
    <td width="250px" align="center">Not Available</td>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <th>Clinic Test Result</th>
<th>Habbits</th>
<th>Allergy</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <?php if(!empty($rows['test_res']) && trim($rows['test_res'])!=''):?>
    <td width="250px"><?php echo $rows['test_res'] ?></td>
    <?php else: ?>
    <td width="250px" align="center">Not Available</td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(!empty($rows['habbits']) && trim($rows['habbits'])!=''):?>
    <td width="250px"><?php echo $rows['habbits'] ?></td>
    <?php else: ?>
    <td width="250px" align="center">Not Available</td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(!empty($rows['allergy']) && trim($rows['allergy'])!=''):?>
    <td width="250px"><?php echo $rows['allergy'] ?></td>
    <?php else: ?>
    <td width="250px" align="center">Not Available</td>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Occupation</th>
<th>PMHx</th>
<th>PSHx</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <?php if(!empty($rows['occup']) && trim($rows['occup'])!=''):?>
    <td width="250px"><?php echo $rows['occup'] ?></td>
    <?php else: ?>
    <td width="250px" align="center">Not Available</td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(!empty($rows['pmhx']) && trim($rows['pmhx'])!=''):?>
    <td width="250px"><?php echo $rows['pmhx'] ?></td>
    <?php else: ?>
    <td width="250px" align="center">Not Available</td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(!empty($rows['pshx']) && trim($rows['pshx'])!=''):?>
    <td width="250px"><?php echo $rows['pshx'] ?></td>
    <?php else: ?>
    <td width="250px" align="center">Not Available</td>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="3">Echo Files</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php if(!empty($data2) && trim($data2)!=''):?>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><center><a href='download_PopUp.php?data=<?php echo $dataFile2; ?>'>Echo Test files exist</a></center></td>
<?php else: ?>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><center>No echo files</center></td>
<?php endif;?>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>P.E</th>
<?php if(!empty($rows['pe']) && trim($rows['pe'])!=''):?>
    <td width="250px"><?php echo $rows['pe'] ?></td>
    <?php else: ?>
    <td width="250px" align="center">Not Available</td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <th rowspan="4" align="left">Signature</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Date</th><td><?php echo $rows['date'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Address of Patient</th><td><?php echo $rows['address'] ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Phone Number of patient</th><td><?php echo $rows['phone_num'] ?></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

And this javascript file to print a div in a page with a css, but dreamweaver software give an error:

```
 function printData()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("mydiv");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
    var css =`table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align:justify;
    }

    th {
        background-color: #7a7878;
        text-align:center
    }`;
   var div = $("<div />", {
    html: '&shy;<style>' + css + '</style>'
  }).appendTo( newWin.document.body);
   newWin.print();

   newWin.close();
}

$('button').on('click',function(){
printData();
});
```

[image]

But in the browser when I hit F12, nothing is given as error, and the css style won't work.

Comment: Do you have es6 updates for your dreamweaver version? better to use babel or some other build tools for it.

Comment: try my code below , bro!

Answer (score 0):

[Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#Browser_compatibility) are not supported in IE. That's probably why dreamweaver throws an error on that line.

Either escape newlines:

```
var myString = 'some \n\
multiline \n\
string';
```

Or concatenate lines:

```
var myString = 'some \n' +
    'multiline \n' +
    'string';
```

Comment: its not me who downvoted but _but dreamweaver software give an error_ this says something else.

Comment: @jai, are there still people use dreamweaver?

Comment: what else to use other than dreamweaver ? I learnt it since college and it is still on my computer. It helps sometime working with displaying graphics without the use of css

Comment: I like sublime or notepad++, but its entirely up to you what you are confortable with using :)

Answer (score -1):

A multiline string in javascript can be made like that in most modern browsers but does not work in IE and older browsers.

You should change

```
var css =`table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align:justify;
}

th {
    background-color: #7a7878;
    text-align:center
}`;
```

to:

```
var css = "table, td, th { \n\
    border: 1px solid black; \n\
    text-align:justify; \n\
} \n\
\n\
th {  \n\
    background-color: #7a7878; \n\
    text-align:center \n\
}";
```

It is even better to make it:

```
var css = "table, td, th { \n"+
"    border: 1px solid black; \n"+
"    txt-align:justify; \n"+
"} \n"+
"th {  \n"+
"    background-color: #7a7878; \n"+
"    text-align:center; \n"+
"}";
```

The reason that your css is not displayed is:
Once IE has processed all the styles loaded with the page, the only reliable way to add another stylesheet is with `document.createStyleSheet(url)`

See the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531194%28VS.85%29.aspx) on createStyleSheet for a few more details.

---

**edit**

So in your case, you can add the above css code to `table.css`, upload it to your server. And at the moment you want to add the style, you use

```
document.createStyleSheet('http://yourserver.com/table.css');
```

Comment: Multiline strings _can_ be created like that in Chrome 41+, Firefox 34+, Opera 28+, and Safari 9+.

Comment: Yes, but its bad practice in my opinion, and it does not work in IE.

Comment: Ok the error gone, but the style does not appear in print preview page @BasvanStein

Comment: See my adjusted answer, I don't know why someone downvoted it.. but ok.

Comment: in my case in your code, where I add document.createStyleSheet(url) and what is url equal to ? @BasvanStein

Comment: It means you need to create a separate stylesheet with your css code, upload it to the server (lets say `https://example.com/style.css`) and then add it with that url.

Comment: Of course, you can also use `jQuery.css()` or the equivalent javascript on each element you want to change.

Comment: can you redit your code by adding what you told me ? Please. I have file named table.css how can I added to your code as document.createStyleSheet(url). @BasvanStein

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93954/discussion-between-bas-van-stein-and-am90).